# Como é que consigo ir buscar informações das drives por c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Boa tarde, foi me pedido para realizar um projeto que consiga ir buscar informações dos *drives* (**C:**, **D:**, etc), como por exemplo quantos drives existem, o nome de cada um, o espaço total e o utilizado.

Mas eu não sei como conseguirei ir buscar essa informação. Será que alguém me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Você fala dos drives do Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe [DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) para obter informações dos drives.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo info in drives)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Nome: {0}\nTamanho: {1}\nTipo de particao: {2}", info.Name, info.TotalSize, info.DriveFormat);
    }
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado é mesmo isso!!

Comment: Não seria _drives_, sem o R?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura obrigado. Já corrigido.